# Trying to write an 'or' query that depends on two different joined tables

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I need to select some rows in a PostgreSQL database using Sequelize where an id exists in joined table 1 OR it exists in joined table 2.

Using Sequelize I tried querying the joined tables inside of 'include' but realized that in some cases, if an id didn't exist then that table was excluded from the resulting rows which isn't what I want. I think that what I want is something more like the following:

```
Model.findAll({
  include: [ Association1, Association2 ],
  where: { [Op.or]: [
    { 'Association1.ModelId': id },
    { 'Association2.ModelId': id }
  ]}
})
```

The code actually produces an error, stating that Model.Assocation1.ModelId doesn't exist. I'm not sure how I'm supposed to accomplish the above code example.

Answer (score 0):

In pure SQL, this will be an `OUTER JOIN` case.

In Sequelize, you probably need to add

```
required: false
```

… to your parameters.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the solution I needed. I was working with outer joins earlier but no combination of outer joins would work. Do I need to use outer joins in conjunction with the where clause above? Where clauses on the joined tables themselves doesn't produce results.